# Help debugging window.event.screenX

Tags: javascript

I'm using firebug and the latest FF to debug this bit of javascript.  When line #30 is hit in the debugger the screen tries to refresh with message

> "To display this page, firefox must
>   send information that will repeat any
>   action (such as a search or order
>   confirmation) that was performed
>   earlier.

Javascript with line #'s  **Called via OnClick()**

```
function EnterComment(divName, /*...couple other params*/) {
25
26 thatDiv = divName;
27 //...comment
28
29 // Mouse Position with offset
30 var x = window.event.screenX + 10;
31 var y = document.body.scrollTop + 20;
```

This doesn't work in IE either.  Is there any way to get an exception from Firebug?  Any other tips to fix this?

Comment: Does Firefox *have* `window.event`?

Comment: is this function called from mousemove event handler?

Comment: @sv_in - Updated post called OnClick()

Comment: You should probably try and not use literals when calculating the mouse position with offset.  There are various properties that can be used to get those value for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have a global "event" object at all. Instead, a reference to an essentially similar object is passed in to event handlers by the runtime system.

I can't tell what sort of code is that fragment you posted. As an example, if you're binding event handlers with the basic DOM 0 attributes, you can do this:

```
<a onclick='yourhandler(event)'>hi</a>
```

and then:

```
function yourhandler(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var X = event.screenX;
  // ...
}
```

If, as you mention in a comment, you were to use jQuery to bind handlers, then it's even easier because it's the same in all browsers:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myAnchor').click(function(event) {
    var X = event.pageX;
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks that helps.  This works in the previous version of the application (tested ONLY in IE).  So, the question is how can I get this to work again?  In other words, is there a jquery or javascript object that can achieve the previous functionality? I want to grab a mouse's position at the point this method was called via OnClick().  I see http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#How_do_I_find_the_mouse_position.3F, but I dont think this will work.

Comment: If you bind event handlers with jQuery, then it's the same in any browser because jQuery normalizes the behavior for you. I'll update my answer.